# Python wrapper to C function producing segmentation error

Tags: python, c, arrays, segmentation-fault, wrapper

I am building a Python wrapper to a C code.

In the `.c` code I have the following defined function

```
double myfunction_at_k_and_z(struct background * pba,
                      struct spectra * psp,
                      struct perturbs *ppt,
                      double k,
                      double z,  
                      double * pk_ic)
{ ...body of the function ...}
```

and in the `.h` file I have

```
  struct background ba;       
  struct perturbs pt;         
  struct spectra sp;
```

Now I implement a function in my `.pyx` file, inside a class `myclass`

```
def get_myfunction(self, double k, double z):
        cdef double dummy
        result = myfunction_at_k_and_z(&self.ba, &self.sp, &self.pt, k, z, &dummy)
        return result
```

and in the `.pxd` file I write:

```
cdef struct background: ....
cdef struct spectra: ...
cdef struct perturbs: ...


double myfunction_at_k_and_z (background * pba, spectra * psp, perturbs *ppt, double k, double z, double * pk_ic)
```

where the dots `...` denote the components of the structures, which are not relevant here apart from one case: in `struct spectra` there are

```
int ln_k_size
double * ln_k
```

Now my problem is that despite everything compiling, when I run with Python my wrapper and use `get_myfunction` through e.g. `myclass.get_myfunction(1., 1.)`, there seems to be a problem with the array `ln_k`, which apparently seems to have `ln_k_size`=0. This causes segmentation error.

Am I missing something in terms of allocation of memory?
Any way out?